# ASP.NET Identity Cookie not being saved/set in subdomain

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity

**Editing** to add in extra details.

I have a web project that I effectively use as an authorization server (e.g. example.com). I then have a few web sites that sit as sub domains (e.g. sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com). I am currently unable to get the `.AspNet.Cookies` cookie to save on the subdomains when logging in to the authorization server. I can see the cookie come back in the response but it's not being set.

I have searched and tried various solutions such as setting the `CookiePath` and `CookieDomain`. I have verified the Machine Key in the `Web.config` file matches between all sites. This is currently how I am enabling Cookie Authentication:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieDomain = ".example.com",
});
```

I have CORS enabled on the authorization server and I am able to receive the Bearer token when I log in, I just can't seem to get the cookie to be saved.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I read somewhere that the ARRAffinity cookie could mess with things so I disabled that as well. I am still unable to see the cookie in the subdomain.

**Edit 2:** Adding the ajax call as requested in the comments (password and domain have been altered for consistency with the post):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/auth/token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: 'admin@example.com',
        password: '************'
    },
    crossDomain: true
});
```

Comment: Hi! When you say that the cookie is not being set you're stating that the browser is not sending it, right? And what values did you try to set in `CookieDomain`? Have you tried `mydomain.com` or `.mydomain.com` (notice the dot in the beginning)?

Comment: When I view the response in fiddler I can see the cookie coming back from the server. But the browser is ignoring the Set-Cookie header for that _specific_ cookie. I have tried `mydomain.com` and `.mydomain.com`, neither make a difference.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample showing how you are creating the cookie?

Comment: I added the code to the post above.

Comment: What type of authentication are you performing? Have you tried setting `AuthenticationType` in `CookieAuthenticationOptions` ? For instance `AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie`.

Comment: I've tried with and without. Just to be clear, the issue here is not the authentication or the issuing of the cookie itself. The client page receives the cookie, it just won't store it. (Not saying your comment wasn't helpful, just trying to add extra context as I think of it.)

Comment: Having the wrong auth type may cause wierd behaviour, like it being sent by the server but being empty and would not be sent in the next requests. You are saying you receive the cookie: Is it possible that it is not well-formed? If so, posting the response headers might help. Also, just to clarify, how are you performing the log in? Are you logging into the authorization server (i.e. via a browser) and then accessing the website in the subdomain? Or is it that your subdomain contains a website that is contacting the authentication server directly and trying to obtain the cookie (i.e. via js)?

Comment: I see where you're going with this. I believe the cookie is formed correctly, I am able to successfully log in (using this exact project) from the primary site (mydomain.com) and when any of the secondary sites are published as sub-applications (mydomain.com/sub1, mydomain.com/sub2, etc.). As for how I am logging in, I have a jQuery ajax call on my client site that is calling the login API on the server site. Again, the only difference here is that the secondary site is no longer a sub-application and is instead now separate. All code is the same.

Comment: Can you add here the code of the jquery call? Also, the response headers would be helpful. Namely the value you are setting in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Added the ajax call. The value I'm setting for Access-Control-Allow-Origin is `http://sub1.example.com` (well okay, not really but it's the correct URL for the sub1 site). I get that you're trying to cover all the angles but if I'm able to hit the auth server and receive a valid response back, shouldn't that already determine that nothing is wrong with that pipeline? If the CORS URL was wrong I would receive an error back from the server, not a 200 response with a cookie, right?

Comment: Your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` seems to be correct and it is behaving as expected. The problem seems to be directly related to how the cookies are handled in CORS and the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` used in ajax requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot at the answer here.

By default, when making cross-site ajax requests, browsers will ignore cookies. More information on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials).

To allow the use of cookies, you must set `withCredentials` to `true` in your requests, like so (more information [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://example.com/auth/token',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: 'admin@example.com',
      password: '************'
   },
   crossDomain: true,
   xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

I've tested this locally and this should be enough if the only thing you need is to authenticate with `example.com` and then keep using the cookie while interacting with `sub1.example.com`.

If you also want to make a request with the cookie to `example.com` and do not want to have your responses ignored by the browser, according to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) you should make sure that `example.com` also returns the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Comment: YES! This was precisely the issue. Adding `withCredentials` to the request and setting `SupportsCredentials = true` in my `CorsPolicy` brought everything together. THANK YOU.